# How can I change the whole structure of a form by clicking a button ( Visual C# Express 2010 )

Tags: forms, visual-c#-express-2010

I'm new here as I am programming with Visual C# Express 2010.

Thats the case:
I have the first form, it contains labels, buttons, textboxes etc. I want one of these buttons to change all the aspects of this first form in order to create a second one.

An example of what I want is an ordinary installer program. It has one form ( I think ). And we have "next" button. Clicking on it, the whole form structure will change.

PS: Im not making an installer program.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be easier simply to develop a new form, and have the button launch an instance of that new form.

That said, you can programatically change aspect of GUI elements by using the appropriate properties.

For example, suppose you have a label `lblStatus` somewhere on the form. You can change its location and text with the following lines:

```
lblStatus.Location = new Point(20, 0);
lblStatus.Text = "Updated Status";
```

Hopefully this is helpful to get you on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

You could do multiple things:

1. Use tab pages for each page of things that you want.  Add a button outside of the tabs that will change to the next one.
2. Add a button and a panel on the form.  Each page of the form is a different `UserControl`.  When you click the button, fill the panel with a new instance of the `UserControl` that you want.
3. Do something like this: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/DesignTimeWizard.aspx
4. Or this: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/c2c412fd-bd28-4e3b-9c20-4dc381ac5199